# datatable shows blank spaces below the paginator links

Tags: laravel, datatable

I'm using larashop admin panel.The datatable shows blank spaces below the datatable..The height blank spaces increases with increase in datatable entries.I don't know what to do..

I tried some css.but none of them helped  me.

```
@extends('templates.admin.layout')
@section('title', 'All Courses')

@section('content')
<div class="">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="x_panel">
                <div class="x_title">
                    <h2>Courses <a href="{{route('course.add')}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Create New </a></h2>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="x_content">
                    <table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-responsive">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Course Name</th>
                                <th>Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Course Name</th>
                                <th>Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                        <tbody>
                            @if(count($courses))
                            @foreach ($courses as $row)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{$row->name}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="{{ route('course.edit', ['id' => $row->id]) }}" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-pencil" title="Edit"></i> </a>
                                    <a href="{{ route('course.show', ['id' => $row->id]) }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" title="Delete"></i> </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                            @endif
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@stop
```

The screenshot of the issue is provided..please check...
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/avqf5.png

Comment: Please formulate your question properly with a better formatting and possibily examples/screenshots if you would like it to be answered. `{{$row->name}} $row->id]) }}" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"> $row->id]) }}` seems to have too many `}}` and `]`

Comment: Could you include a link to the Larashop package/framework that you're using?

Comment: https://github.com/dwijitsolutions/laraadmin-crm

Comment: it's the one that i'm using..